# SVG without width/height renders with a natural size

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this SVG which doesn't have a `width` or `height` attribute
I have the following HTML

```
<div class="block">
   <img src="https://s3-eu....vAmfIxVv/kiwi.svg">
</div>
```

With the following css

```
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}

img {
    width: 100%;  
}
```

Although I want the svg to be 100% in width, it renders in chrome with some weird width/height (Only in firefox it has a dimensions of 0x0)

[image]

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0r65ey2d/14/)

So any suggestions where this natural `width` comes from and why isn't the width 100% ?

Is it possible to make the `svg` width 100% ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want auto width on the `<svg>` elements, you should simply use `display: block` on the parent `<div>`, but use `max-width: 100%` on the SVG elements themselves. Chrome somehow fails to enforce proper width calculations when SVGs are contained within an inline-block element:

```
.block {
  display: block;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Proof-of-concept example:

```css
section {
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.block {
  display: block;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.svg {
   border: 1px solid red; 
}
```

```html
<section>
   <div class="block svg">
       <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-eu.hipchat.com/46194/456229/JCHA4rtvAmfIxVv/kiwi.svg" alt="">
   </div>

   <div class="block">
      <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/100x200" alt="">
   </div>
</section>
```