# Position absolute `div` inside position relative parent `div` disappearing on chrome and edge

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome

I am trying to create a react component and position it on the page.

The component consists of multiple `div`s with `position: absolute` so that I can stack them on top of each other. The parent containing all these `div`s has `position: relative` and size `400px x 400px`.

On firefox, everything works absolutely fine. However, on chrome or edge, the component renders but disappears off the viewport.

**Edit:**

#### [Here is a jsfiddle of my code](https://jsfiddle.net/raniceyue/zro78935/26/)

When you access the jsfiddle using firefox, you can see concentric circles, when you access it using chrome, nothing shows up unless you disable `position: absolute` on the child components.

#### Research

From my research on this issue, this disappearing problem only occurs when the `position: absolute` children are unable to find a parent with `position: relative`, however this is not the problem for my implementation.

Trying using dev console on chrome, when I turn `position: absolute` off for all child components, the `div`s appear but no longer stack on top of each other.

Does anyone know why this is happening? How come it's only working on firefox, and is there any way to fix this so that the component can be viewed on all browsers?

## Update

As per the accepted answer, the solution was to specify a `width` and `height` for the child `div`s containing SVGs. This is because for some reason some browsers do not automatically calculate width and height for SVGs. This is explained in the comments of this post, as well as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672536/svg-without-width-height-renders-with-a-natural-size).

Comment: This is not reproducible with just the snippets of HTML & CSS you have shown us so far (even if the missing class name you used in the CSS is compensated for) – https://jsfiddle.net/sbfLy230/ If the fact that this is implemented in react changes anything about the structure that would be relevant here, then you need to find a way to present us a proper example of that then.

Comment: @CBroe Hi, thanks for the tip, I'm woking on the jsfiddle now. Apologies as I just recently started using react therefore I am not sure about how react changes the structure of the code. Is it ok if you can explain it to me?

Comment: Your children elements appear to be in the correct position, but they all don’t have a width - apparently due to the fact, that you put SVG into them. Replace the SVGs with just plain text, and they show up where you’d expect them to. Chrome does not appear to render these SVG with any default width in this setting, so you will probably have to explicitly specify one. (`svg { width: 20px; }` or similar added to your styles, makes the element show up as expected.)

Comment: @CBroe thank you! I get it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give width to all circles as they become independent when you give them `position: absolute`. So modify your css code like this:

```
.child1, .child2, .child3 {
    position: absolute; /* Turn off to see circles in chrome*/
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks me later.

Answer (score 0):

you just missed the width and height for child div `

```
 .child1, .child2, .child3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
   }
```